# Return ParseObject from cloud code to Unity client

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-cloud-code

I'm trying to figure out how to return a ParseObject to my Unity client from cloud code.

Here's a simple function in the cloud:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getCard", function(request, response) {

    console.log("getting card " + request.params.name);

    var query = new Parse.Query("Card");

    query.equalTo("name", request.params.name).first().then(function (card) {

        console.log("got card " + card.id);

        response.success(card);

    }, function (error) {

        console.log("error " + error.message);

        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

All the logs are fine, it finds the card, the id looks good and returns it.

Unity is calling and handling like so:

```
public Task<ParseCard> GetCard(string name) {

    Dictionary<string, object> args = new Dictionary<string, object>() {

        { "name", name }
    };

    return ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<ParseCard>("getCard", args);
}

GetCard("MyCard").Then(card => Debug.Log(card), error => Debug.Log(error));
```

I get the following exception in Unity

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: s
  at System.DateTime.ParseExact (System.String s, System.String[] formats, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style) [0x00013] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/DateTime.cs:1882 
  at System.DateTime.ParseExact (System.String s, System.String format, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style) [0x0001c] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/DateTime.cs:1870 
  at System.DateTime.ParseExact (System.String s, System.String format, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/DateTime.cs:1030 
  at Parse.Internal.ParseDecoder.ParseDate (System.String input) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Parse.ParseObject.MergeMagicFields (IDictionary`2 data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Parse.ParseObject.MergeFromServer (IDictionary`2 data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Parse.ParseObject.MergeAfterFetch (IDictionary`2 result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Parse.Internal.ParseDecoder.Decode (System.Object data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Parse.Internal.ParseDecoder.Decode (System.Object data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Parse.Internal.ParseCloudCodeController.<CallFunctionAsync>b__0[ParseObject] (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1 t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass1`2[System.Tuple`2[System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]],Parse.ParseObject].<OnSuccess>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7`1[Parse.ParseObject].<OnSuccess>b__6 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task+<>c__DisplayClass3`1+<>c__DisplayClass5[System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Parse.ParseObject]].<ContinueWith>b__2 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```